# Java App and Solr connection

Tags: solr, solrj

i have protected my solr admin page with tomcat basic authentication because by default is opened.

But now i cannot connect from the tomcat_java application (server1) to solr (server2) when is protected with password. When site is open is working properly.

we have changed: /ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/config.properties

```
the solr url:
from:
solr.url=http://solr.example.com
to
solr.url=http://user:pass@solr.example.com
```

but is not connecting and showing this error:

```
2015-08-24 12:10:17,774 DEBUG [HttpClientUtil] - Creating new http client, config:maxConnections=128&maxConnectionsPerHost=32&followRedirects=false
2015-08-24 12:10:17,775 DEBUG [PoolingClientConnectionManager] - Connection request: [route: {}->http://solr.example.com][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 32; total allocated: 0 of 128]
2015-08-24 12:10:17,781 DEBUG [PoolingClientConnectionManager] - Connection leased: [id: 8][route: {}->http://solr.example.com][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 32; total allocated: 1 of 128]
2015-08-24 12:10:17,781 DEBUG [DefaultClientConnectionOperator] - Connecting to solr.example.com:80
2015-08-24 12:10:17,795 ERROR [Dispatcher] - Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)

....
```

In which file i have to configure user and password to connect to solr?

thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Once I configured the solr using [this](http://muddyazian.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-require-password-authentication.html). This configuration is inside the solr jetty server. In this user, password are specified in a separate file.